# Shows either list or tuple index out of bound error in following code

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

i have written a code. The way I want this code to work is commented. So you can try that to know the purpose(Generally to calculate the average of the elements). But when i am running the actual code of function rainaverage it is showing list index out of bound error and when I perform some tweaks to fix it it shows tuple out of bound error. So your help would be appreciated:

```
'''L1=[(2,3),(4,3),(5,6),(2,5)]
m=L1[0][1]
b=L1[0][0]
n=L1[3][1]
a=(m+n)/2
L1.pop([0][0])
L1.pop([2][0])
L2=(b,a)
L1=list(L1)
L1.append(L2)
L1=tuple(L1)
print(L1)'''
def rainaverage(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(len(l)):
            if(l[i]==l[j+1]):
                m=l[i][1]
                n=l[j+1][1]
                b=l[0][0]
                a=(m+n)/2
                l = list(l)
                l.pop([i][0])
                l.pop([j+1][0])
                l2=(b,a)

                l.append(l2)
                l=tuple(l)

    print(l)

l3=[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,1),(3,8)]
rainaverage(l3)
```

Comment: Can you explain what this function is trying to do?  I'm having trouble following the logic of the comment

Comment: That is extremely hard to read code due to the useless variable names and lack of information about what it's supposed to be doing, lack of the specific error information details, and the code you claim is *commented* doesn't contain a single comment. It makes it really difficult for us to help you.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  It's just doing average. Let me explain you with example. This is our list[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,1),(3,8)]. Here there are three tuples having (1,a) in a list where a can be any integer. So its just calculating the average of that 2nd element like(1,2)(1,3),(1,1) so 2+3+1=6                                               
6/3=2.0.  So the remaing list is [(1,2.0),(2,3),(3,8)]. That's it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use a dictionary mapping first values to lists of second values.  Then you can take the average of those lists individually

```
from collections import defaultdict

def rainaverage(l):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for a, b in l:
        d[a].append(b)
    return [(k, sum(v)/len(v)) for k, v in d.items()]

L1=[(2,3),(4,3),(5,6),(2,5)]

print(rainaverage(L1))
# [(2, 4.0), (4, 3.0), (5, 6.0)]
print(rainaverage([(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,1),(3,8)]))
# [(1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (3, 8.0)]
```